# Why VSCode fonts always look bold in macOS?

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code

- Vs code : Consolas font looks bold

[image: image1]

- Sublime text 3: Looks normal

[image: image2]

- VS Code default font:

[image: image3]

Even though in the settings I set font weight to 100, nothing works. What's the problem?

MBP 2015 Retina, Sierra 10.12.6, VsCode 1.33.1

Comment: Using external display with resolution lower than retina's. However in Sublime everything worked fine

Comment: They all look pretty much the same to me. Did you check your uploaded images, all on the same screen?

Comment: The font weight you want must be present on the system. Font geometries are not dynamic. // All I can see is that VS Code renders text completely different from Sublime.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after I was messing with font smoothing from this article [fixing osx blurry fonts](https://blog.macsales.com/46527-is-macos-mojave-making-some-fonts-blurry-heres-how-to-fix-it/).
When I did the following command to undo the settings I had messed with, vscode went back to the thin beautiful font.

```
defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool YES
```